# Using rich:jquery without the selector

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

Below is my code to put mash value for my text box.

```
<h:inputText id="time" value="#{configMaster.time}" style="width:40px;" maxlength="5">  
<rich:jQuery selector="#time" query="mask('99:99', {placeholder:' '})" timing="onload"/>  
</h:inputText>
```

But my problem is I'm creating dynamic text boxes using `<c:forEach>` like

```
<c:forEach items="#{maintTable.columnDataList}" var="col" varStatus="loop">
<h:inputText value="#{configMaster.time}" style="width:40px;" maxlength="5">  
<rich:jQuery query="mask('99:99', {placeholder:' '})" timing="onload"/>  
</h:inputText>
</c:forEach>
```

Here the problem is the `id` will be dynamic so I can't give `selector`. Is there any way to make it work for all my text boxes. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a CSS class.

```
<h:inputText ... styleClass="masked" />
...
<rich:jQuery selector=".masked" ... />
```

Comment: thanks BalusC. if i have 2 style classes then do i need to give both or one is enough. styleclass `inputText` is common for all textboxes. but i want the <rich:jQuery> to be applied only for the text boxes have `distTime` style class.